# Under which circumstances does muscle hyperplasia happen in humans?

Tags: muscles, development

What circumstances allow humans to have muscle hyperplasia in the prenatal and immediately postnatal period that doesn't exist later?

Is it about specific hormones that follow through our veins?

Comment: IMHO, this question would be a better fit on [Health.SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Remi.b : Given that it's about developmental biology I don't see how it's better at Health.SE

Comment: You're talking about a medical condition at birth. It sure is related to human developmental biology but also human health. The fact that you phrase your question as "Under which circumstances" make the question sounds like a medical question to me. But that was just my opinion and I tend to be willing to migrate more things to Health.SE than most users I think. Other users might disagree with me.